# How to convert image(static openstreetmap) into base64 string using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, openstreetmap

I need to convert a static map image.I found the following code:

```
function toDataURL(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
}

toDataURL('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d50c83cc0c6523b4d3f6085295c953e0', function(dataUrl) {
  console.log('RESULT:', dataUrl)
})
```

The problem is that any other image is generated very well, but from this link:

http://staticmap.openstreetmap.de/staticmap.php?center=52.6240,20,3744&zoom=10&size=640x640&maptype=mapnik&format=png

This does not work :(

Link to items such as DOM works, but this conversion is not working. Do you have any idea what's wrong with my link?

Thanks for any replies :)

Comment: The server you load the image from must “allow” you to do this. Gravatar sends an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header for this purpose - but OpenStreeMap doesn’t.

Comment: And maybe you know another solution to this problem?

Comment: If OpenStreetMap does not offer a way to request those images in a way that allows this (you’d have to check with them), then you simply can’t do it on the client side; you’d have to use a server-side component to request that image from the URL and save it.

Comment: OK thanks for the information :)

Comment: This service is provided by the German OSM community, more specifically by FOSSGIS e.V.. That's quite different from openstreetmap.org, which is run by the OSM Foundation. Best is to contact FOSSGIS e.V. or the German community and ask for assistance. help.openstreetmap.org might also be a good place to reach out to the relevant folks.